# which is the real python3 executable's path?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, terminal

On my Mac I installed xcode and python3. In terminal I type 'which python3', it shows '/usr/bin/python3'. then I type 'python3' to get into the interactive environment, then type

import sys

sys.executable

'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3'.

Oh! why it comes to the executable in xcode, not '/usr/bin/python3'?

Comment: What do you get when you run `ls -l /usr/bin/python3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/python3` in a Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

because it's probably a linked file. cd inside your /usr/bin directory and type `ls -r | grep python`. You can find more info about links here: https://www.linux.com/tutorials/understanding-linux-links/